# Where does Sora dissapear to in KH3?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-3

In KH3 at the end Sora disappears. I have heard he goes to "The world ends with you" but I don't know for sure. Where does he go?

Comment: I'm curious what sort of answer you're expecting.  It's the end of the game, and I'm not aware of any additional information that would help answer that.

Comment: Its funny how many views I get on here, but I don't get any on my YouTube channel haha XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, we do not fully know where Sora vanishes to. The ending of Kingdom Hearts 3 was very vague on this information.

It is speculated that Sora ended up the game's version of Shibuya, as shown in the secret ending. This is only information we currently have as to Sora's whereabouts. However, it is unclear if it is Shibuya from the game *The World Ends With You* or the in-game world of *Verum Rex* since the secret ending also shows Yozora.

Kingdom Hearts 3 Re:Mind is set to release early 2020, so we have to wait and see on what will be revealed in the new story content. Until then, any answer will be speculative